# Snap uninstallation process fails

Tags: 16.04, snap

I installed ubuntu-clock-app. Once I had to emergency turn off my computer (hard reset), this application has stopped working.

```
datafile4@datafile4-K53SD:~$ sudo snap remove ubuntu-clock-app
error: can't remove "ubuntu-clock-app": cannot find mounted snap "ubuntu-clock-app" at revision 5
```

At the same time

```
datafile4@datafile4-K53SD:~$ sudo snap install ubuntu-clock-app
error: can't install "ubuntu-clock-app": snap "ubuntu-clock-app" already installed
```

snap changes result:

```
Status  Spawn                 Ready                 Summary
Done    2016-05-01T07:51:19Z  2016-05-01T07:51:20Z  Make snap "ubuntu-clock-app" unavailable to the system
Undone  2016-05-01T07:51:19Z  2016-05-01T07:51:21Z  Remove security profile for snap "ubuntu-clock-app"
Done    2016-05-01T07:51:19Z  2016-05-01T07:51:20Z  Remove data for snap "ubuntu-clock-app"
Error   2016-05-01T07:51:19Z  2016-05-01T07:51:20Z  Remove snap "ubuntu-clock-app" from the system
Hold    2016-05-01T07:51:19Z  2016-05-01T07:51:20Z  Discard interface connections for snap "ubuntu-clock-app"

......................................................................
Remove snap "ubuntu-clock-app" from the system

2016-05-01T11:51:20+04:00 ERROR remove /snap/ubuntu-clock-app/5/bin/clock: read-only file system
```

Comment: I have the same problem but a snap build by me.  If you find a solution, please write the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way out of this, if you don't care to lose the data associated with the snaps, is to run [Zyga's reset state script](https://github.com/zyga/devtools/blob/master/reset-state).

Also, please make sure you're on snapd 2.0.3, which was released to xenial last week; that way you shouldn't get into this state again.